# tar with --include pattern

Tags: tar

The following is a snippet from a script I have that tries
to tar up all php files in a subdir.  It tries to use the '--include' parameter
but does not seem to work (output is from 'set -x' in bash)

```
+ find . -name '*.php'
./autoload.php
./ext/thrift_protocol/run-tests.php
./protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php
...
./transport/TTransportFactory.php
+ tar -cvjf my.tar.bz2 '--include=*.php' .
+ set +x
```

The `find` found several php files but tar does not seem to see them.  If I take out the `--include` all files are tarred.

I know I can use find to feed a list
(`find . -name '*.php' -print0 | tar -cvjf "my.tar.bz2" --null -T -`), but whats wrong with the `--include` param?

Comment: belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: hmm if so - should there really be a `tar` tag on SO?

Comment: @nhed Neither `GNU tar` nor `BSD tar` recognize `--include`. What version of `tar` are you using ?

Comment: @cnicutar thanks - that probably my problem, this is tar on my MacBookPro, reporting `bsdtar 2.6.2 - libarchive 2.6.2`.   If you can repeat this as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @nhed Actually I just looked into `tar(1)` on *my* freebsd system and I found an `--include` option (earlier I had looked on some old man page online). I'll get back with more info :)

Comment: @cnicutar it doesn't seem to be portable, so I'd rather use the portable option combining find and tar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually I just looked into `tar(1)` on my freebsd system and I found an --include option (earlier I had looked on some old man page online). The `--include` options is quite powerful. Here are some examples

**These are the files**

```
cnicutar@uranus ~/tar_test $ ls -1
a.c
b.c
x
```

**Simple tar, archive everything**

```
cnicutar@uranus ~/tar_test $ tar -cvf archive1.tar *
a a.c
a b.c
a x
```

**Archive only C files**

```
cnicutar@uranus ~/tar_test $ tar -cvf archive2.tar --include='*.c' *
a a.c
a b.c
```

So what is probably wrong in your script is that you give tar `.` instead of `.*` as the last argument.

**EDIT**

I have tried it and was surprised. The behavior of `tar(1)` is unexpected but (I believe) intended. The man page says:

```
Process only files or directories that match the specified pattern.
```

So when you specify the pattern it filters out any directories that don't match it. So if your directories don't happen to have that extension (it's valid but uncommon) **it won't descend into them** (even if deep inside there might be "interesting" files).

So in conclusion I believe it would be best to use another way to recursively enumerate + filter files.

Comment: Did you try any recursion?  unlike `zip`,  `tar` is by default is recursive.  This seems to break here.  I liked better the **it not portable, don't use it** approach.  I mean why even have it if I could accomplish the same thing with `tar -cvf x.tar *.c` ?

Comment: Is this command not adequate for taring all `*.c` files?: `tar -cvf archive2.tar *.c`

Comment: --include option doesn't exist in gnu tar as of v1.30!

Comment: my Gnu tar `1.28` also doesn't have `--include` option.

Comment: As of the GNU version 1.32, `tar` does not include the `--include` flag.

Answer (score 137):

GNU **tar** has a [***-T*** or ***--files-from*** option](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#files) that can take a file containing a list of files to include. The file specified with this option can be "-" for stdin. So, you can pass an arbitrary list of files for tar to archive from stdin using ***-files-from -***. Using **find** patterns to generate a list of files, your example becomes:

```
find . -name '*.php' -print0 | tar -cvjf my.tar.bz2 --null --files-from -
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work for me, but this is great!

Comment: Also, if you want to have things that match multiple patterns go into the tar file, you could do something like this:
find . -regex ".*\.php" -o -regex ".*\.css" | tar cvzf stuff.tgz --files-from -

Comment: This wouldn't include empty direcories, would it?

Comment: Daniel, the way it's written, no. But you may be able to add a parameter to find to produce names of the directories you want to include.

Comment: It's obvious, but to be noted, `find . -name '*.php'` could be replaced with any command that helps you to find specific files/directories; e.g. running a PHP file which it handles and outputs all the paths you want to backup, separated by new lines (i.e., the command would be something like `php -f find.php`).

Comment: This is incorrect. `--files-from` gives _filenames_, not patterns. So you can’t use wildcards here.

This appears to be functionality that GNU tar lacks that BSD tar provides. Alas.

Comment: @PeregrineYankee. You're correct, that option takes a list of filenames, not patterns. It's the find command that generates a list of files based on provided patterns. I tried to rephrase the answer more carefully. Thanks.

Comment: `-print0` with `--null` is used to safely interpret new lines, good answer

Comment: It is important to note, that the output and what will be in the tar.gz file will be completely different if the parameter order is not used as defined in the given answer. I.e. `find . -print0 -name '*.php'`